# How to use custom neighborhood/city/state for registration on drupal or elgg?

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, elgg

I'm implementing a social networking site.  I hope to use drupal or elgg and am trying out both.  I'm stuck on customizing the registration to include a neighborhood in addition to city and state.

I want to have drop-down menus customize the local information based on the more global information.  So, once you choose the state, the city list is populated in a drop-down menu.

I am building a list of the interesting neighborhoods, and can load that into a db table or whatever is convenient.

What do you suggest?

Javascript and/or php is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want a module like [Active Select](http://drupal.org/project/activeselect) ([Drupal 6 port here](http://drupal.org/node/298230)) that provides that sort of functionality to the Forms API.

Answer (score 0):

for elgg .. there are two plugins you will find usefull.

1. forms - http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/kevin/read/97061/form-and-related-plugins-for-elgg-15-and-higher
2. flex profiles - http://groups.google.com/group/elgg-development/browse_thread/thread/15bb22b7b5fc665e

hope this points you in a helpful direction.

you can even use csv and this plugin... to fill out all the info dynamically.

http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/naakka/read/165550/upload-users